# android service not defining layout

Tags: android, audio, service, wakelock

I have made this service to play a sound, I could be way off base with what I created because I was following a simple tutorial that was not even close to what I tried to do. in any case I have it set on my main activity that when the button is clicked it should launch this service. the service has errors in the build and I can not run it. In the onCreate(); it has errors at the SetContentView and the FindViewById lines. I would like to know why that is happening and if this is even the correct way to use a service to play a sound so the screen wont time out.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Shipservice extends Service implements View.OnClickListener {
public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button2;
public Spinner spinner2;
public PowerManager.WakeLock wl;  
static final String TAG=Shipservice.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
 PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "wake");

    super.onCreate();
    wl.acquire();
    setContentView(R.layout.ship);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
}
// Play the sound and start the timer
private void playSound(int resourceId) {
    // Cleanup any previous sound files
    cleanup();
    // Create a new media player instance and start it

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    // Create the timer to stop the sound after x number of milliseconds
    int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);
}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn2:
        playSound(R.raw.ocean_ship);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cleanup();
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy'd");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart'd");
}

public void cleanup() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;

    }
    // Cancel any previously running tasks
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

// Runnable task used by the handler to stop the sound
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cleanup();
    }
};


protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    wl.release();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us where the errors are occurring?  It's unreasonable to expect people to start a project and copy your code into it in order to see what you're talking about.,

Comment: Mind asking you what were the errors. Pls edit your post and add your errors as well.

Comment: can you inflate a layout for a service? as far as i know services dont have any UI.. only Activities have a UI for which you can setContentView(Layout) in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

A Service does not have a user interface!   Create an Activity to interact with the user and have it forward the requests to a service via startService(intent)

---

In response to the question in the comment:

Create a new class derived from IntentService.
  In that class, implement the onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method.
  Add a declaration of the new service in the Manifest file.

In your application:
  When the user takes an action that should cause a sound to play:
     Create an Intent that explicitly reference your new service.
     Add Extra information to the intent to tell the service what to do
      (you could also use the Action field of the intent for this)
    call the startService(intent) method to send the intent to the service.

Which functions should be moved to the service, I'll leave up to you.  Basically anything that takes longer than a few milliseconds should be in the service.

There are lots of examples available.   Google something like IntentService play sound to find them.

Comment: That would explain the error at the set content view. So basically I have an activity that plays a sound and has a UI with it but I was told that I needed to have a service handle the sound playing instead. How should I split that off?